# Passing file handle as function arg in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to be able to have a function that prints to a file but that does not open the file -- instead an already open file handle should be passed to it.  That way the file opening and closing only happen once in the calling block of code.

I tried:

```
sub teeOutput
{
    my $str = $_[0];
    my $hndl = $_[1];

    #print to file
    print $hndl $str;
    #print to STDOUT
    print $str;
}
```

and then when calling that

```
open(RPTHANDLE, ">", $rptFilePath) || die("Could not open file ".$rptFilePath);

&teeOutput('blahblah', RPTHANDLE);
&teeOutput('xyz', RPTHANDLE);

close(RPTHANDLE);
```

but that didn't work.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, stop using global variables for file handles.

```
open(my $RPTHANDLE, ">", $rptFilePath)
   or die("Could not open file $rptFilePath: $!\n");
```

Then... Well, there is no "then".

```
teeOutput($RPTHANDLE, 'blahblah');
teeOutput($RPTHANDLE, 'xyz');
close($RPTHANDLE);
```

Notes:

- I reversed the argument to `teeOutput` to something saner.
- I removed the directive (`&`) to override `teeOutput`'s prototype. `teeOutput` doesn't even have one.

(But if you have to deal with globs, use `teeOutput(\*STDERR, ...);`.)

Comment: what does the directive (&) do?  i tried googling but didn't find much.  i used it because i thoughty you are always supposed to use it in front of a function call.  i come from a Java background -- so i always grind my teeth at how you can do the same think in Perl in a multitude of different ways, which to me is only confusing as there apparently always is one right way while other ways are legal but not recommended.  Same with $RPTHANDLE vs RPTHANDLE.

Comment: As I mentioned, it overrides the sub's prototype. Your sub doesn't even have a prototype.